# Mutable variable is accessible from closure in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there are already questions to this problem but I couldn't make out the solution in my case.
I want to reset a $scope value after using it, but I can't access i in the callback function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.objects.length; i++) {
    Priority.create({
        "priority": $scope.selectedPriority[i].priority,
    }, function (priority) {
        $scope.selectedPriority[i].priority = undefined;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function callbackFor(i, priority) {
      $scope.selectedPriority[i].priority = undefined;
    }

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.objects.length; i++) {
    Priority.create({
        "priority": $scope.selectedPriority[i].priority,
    }, callbackFor(i, priority));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because this way, priority is undefined. It's the "result" of Priority.create